# Asp Net Core (2.1) WebApp - Auth for API and Web interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I've created an AspNetCore(2.1) WebApp  that has an API controller secured using `JwtBearer` authentication.

In `ConfigureServices` I have:

```
services.AddAuthentication(...).AddJwtBearer(...)
```

In my API Controller I have:

```
[Authorize]

[ApiController]

public class BillingController : ControllerBase

{ ...
```

This all works perfectly well.

Now I want to add some HTML pages to the WebApp that are secured by 'traditional' sessions.

These pages will contain javascript/ajax that *will also call the API methods to gather data*.

Is there a recommended approach/template/example for combining these authentication methods?

Comment: "that are secured by 'traditional' sessions":  do you means  these pages protected by cookie authentication?

Comment: not necessarily, but that would be ok @itminus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your WebAPI endpoints were protected by JwtBearer Authentication Scheme, and now you want to enable requests from a WebPage that is protected by Cookie Authentication Scheme to access this WebAPI Endpoint.

Since the request from a webpage usually contains a cookie, you can change the `DefaultPolicy` for `[Authorize()]` attribute to allow both JwtBearer & Cookie Authentication Scheme at the same time:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie()
    .AddJwtBearer(options=>{ ... });

services.AddAuthorization(opts =>{
    opts.DefaultPolicy = 
        new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
});
```

To protect the WebAPI endpoints with JwtBearer/Cookie, simply annotate the action method/controller with a `[Authorize]`:

```cs
[Authorize]
public string Hello(){
    return "top secret";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would assume that the 'traditional' sessions which include Javascript, ajax,...  will be the **View Engine** and in this case, I think It will be the Razor (The default View Engine of ASP.Net core, it takes the Razor code in the View file and switches it to the HTML response). For more information, you can go to: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/web-api